# Paypal subscription integration php

Tags: php, paypal, subscription

I have spent all day on something that should only take a couple of minutes.

I need to add a subscription service onto a website, the user needs to enter their full name and email address as part of the subscription, paypal should then take the payment and redirect back to the site while passing the full name and email so accounts can be created.

I am at a loss here as their documentation is all over the place and conflicts with itself.  How do I create a subscription button with the additional fields and get it all working.

And how the hell do I test it?  I have attempted creating one with the subscription button on the paypal site but when the checkout is completed it doesn't go back to the site to create the fields unless you press the button and when you do there is nothing no post data no get data nothing!

Comment: Check this out: http://net.tutsplus.com/tag/paypal/

Comment: @JosephSilber thanks for this some reason this didn't pop up in google searches, post as the answer and i'll accept it

Comment: @JosephSilber Sadly i followed this word for word and it hasn't worked, took a payment and no account created and no email received

Answer (score 0):

You could try using PHP-Payment it allows you to redirect to a page upon success. https://github.com/phpfour/php-payment/tree/master/src/php/Rbs